# How to set jdbc source connector configuration for epoch timestamp

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a table on SQL server that has column store epoch/unix time, and I want to source the table using jdbc connector and using mode timestamp+incrementing. how to use the epoch column as timestamp column and get update for every update and new row from table.

```
mode: timestamp+incrementing
poll.interval.ms: 2000
incrementing.column.name: Id
timestamp.column.name: changeAt
auto.create: true
validate.non.null: False
```

I used this config and success source row to kafka topic when timestamp column using datetime2 data type and not working when I change to use data type big int for epoch

is it possible do this using jdbc connector what config that i should add